# How do I stop init from being called from another class in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, view, transition, init

In Cocos2d I have 2 classes, HelloWorldScene (The standard main class for the Cocos2d template) and OptionsScene. I launch OptionsScene from HelloWorldScene and than when I'm done using OptionsScene I launch HelloWorldScene from OptionScene.

My problem is init is called when I launch HelloWorldScene from OptionsScene and I don't want to let init be called because it essentially resets my game.

Here is the code I am using to launch HelloWorldScene from OptionsScene:

```
HelloWorld *hw = [HelloWorld alloc];
[hw loadWithParticleColor:particleColor andBloppleColor:bloppleColor];
[hw release];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionRotoZoom transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorld node]]];
```

Any hints or solutions would be of great help!

Comment: Make a HelloWorld pointer in the .h file, allocate and init it once when you start the app, and move to it when you want to move to that scene. Remember to Dealloc it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a relatively simple hierarchy, you can use the CCDirector's pushScene: method and add the OptionsScene on top of the HelloWorldScene. Dismiss with popScene and your HelloWorldScene should appear in the state you left it in.

Replacing the scene is usually used when you want to conserve resources, which is not necessary in this case.